# How to create a customized Jackson annotation to append property on serialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I would like to create a customized [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) annotation like that:

```
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
//... Other Jackson annotations...
@interface SelfLink {
    
    Class<? extends Entity> type();
    
    String uriTemplate() default "";

}
```

I would like to use this annotation on classes or fields like this:

```
@Getter
@SelfLink(type = Alpha.class)
class Alpha extends Entity {

    private String name;

    public Alpha(Long id, String name) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Getter
class Beta {

    private String uuid;

    @SelfLink(type = Gamma.class)
    private Entity data;

}

@Getter
class Gamma extends Entity {

    private String stuff;

    public Gamma(Long id, String stuff) {
        super(id);
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

}
```

The customized Jackson annotation would be used to append extra fields. I tried to use `@JsonSerialize(using = SelfLinkSerializer.class)` on the `SelfLink` annotation to define a Serializer:

```
@JsonComponent
class SelfLinkSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Mirror mirror = new Mirror();

    @Autowired
    private LinkResolver linkResolver;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private SelfLinkSerializer() {
        this(Object.class, 
            new LinkResolver() {
                @Override
                public <T extends Entity> String resolve(Class<? extends Entity> type, T instance) {
                    return "always-null";
                }
            }
        );
    }

    SelfLinkSerializer(Class<Object> t, LinkResolver linkResolver) {
        super(t);
        this.linkResolver = linkResolver;
    }

    @Autowired
    public SelfLinkSerializer(LinkResolver linkResolver) {
        this(Object.class, linkResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
    
        this.serializeContentWithoutThisSerializer(value, gen, provider);
    
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    private void serializeContentWithoutThisSerializer(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        String jsonContent = this.serializeContentViaGson(value, gen, provider); 
    
        gen.writeRaw(jsonContent);
    }

    private String serializeContentViaGson(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) {
        JsonElement jsonElement = this.gson.toJsonTree(value);
    
        SelfLink selfLink = this.mirror.on(value.getClass()).reflect().annotation(SelfLink.class).atClass();
        if(selfLink != null) {
            Class<? extends Entity> type = selfLink.type();
            String link = value instanceof Entity ? this.linkResolver.resolve(type, (Entity) value) : null; 
        
            jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("link", link);
        }
        String json = this.gson.toJson(jsonElement);
        String trimmed = CharMatcher.is('{').trimFrom(json);
        trimmed = CharMatcher.is('}').trimTrailingFrom(trimmed);
        return trimmed;
    }

}
```

The original idea was to start the JSON ("{"), use Jackson engine to generate the content, my serializer would resolve the link, append it on the JSON ("link":"..."), and close the JSON ("}"). But I hit a wall: I did not find a way reuse Jackson. My workaround so far is to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), but that is a monstrosity. Gson do not honor Jackson annotations. I would need to create an algorithm to convert all Jackson annotations and that is a "NO-NO".

I am kinda locked on some versions of Spring Boot and Jackson (1.5.8.RELEASE and 2.8.10 respectively). I created a [Gist with the whole example, and a pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/theoamonteiro/b55955ae1dc13fe2e5feeb153914b0e4).

I have a secondary issue because even as a [@JsonComponent](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsoncomponent), Spring is not injecting the `@Autowired LinkResolver linkResolver`. For now I also do not know how to make `@SelfLink` work on fields like on `Beta` class. Bur for now my question is:

**How is it possible to use the Jackson API to generate the string with the JSON representation for the `value` param in the `public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException` method?**

Comment: I may have not exactly understood your problem. Therefore I don't know if it works for you: you can create a custom Jackson serializer/deserializer just by extending JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer classes and override serialize/deserialize methods.

Comment: Hi @OnurBaştürk, I already created a Serializer. The problem is how to serialize the object (create a string representation of the JSON), and after append my link property. If I try to use `JsonGenerator.writeObject(Object pojo)` it enters in a infinite loop and not ironically results on a stack overflow.
```
gen.writeStartObject();

gen.writeObject(value);
//... write link property
gen.writeEndObject();
```
What could I use instead of **gen.writeObject(value)** to serialize the content of `value` without getting a infinite recursion?